# CS50 - Why am I unable to run application.py using flask run. It throws the error -"Do not use the development server in a production environment."

Tags: python, flask

This is my code for application.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/zuck")
def zuck():
    return render_template("zuck.html")

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html")
```

This is pretty much the same as what David types out but when I type flask run in the terminal window, it throws up a bunch of nasty errors 
[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ItH4.png)

Please help! What could the issue be?

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. If you are not running this in a production environment you are fine.

Comment: This has always been strongly suggested in Flask but I think in 1.0 they made the warning in red text. That's why it may not look the same as whatever guide you're following

Comment: But clearly I am in a production environment because it says so right there. How do I switch to WSGI?

Comment: No it doesn't. It says _if you are in a production environment_. If you are not familiar with this error then it's very unlikely you have your app in production, you're just doing development. [These are the deployment options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/) when you move to production.

Comment: Read above that line, it does say 'environment: production'. But thanks to Stephen, the link he shared helped me fix it. Now it says 'environment: development'.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know how Flask makes that distinction, I will look into what it is actually trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn of debug mode, you can do that in the `app.run` function call

```
app.run(debug=False)
```

But as Dietrich Epp mentioned in the comment, it's not an error, just a warning.

You can read more about flask debug mode [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/).